# How to trigger microphone permission popup on chrome (javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, permissions, microphone

How can i trigger this modal on javascript button click

[image]

Comment: @Hakan just a note – it's `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` now (used to be just `navigator.getUserMedia`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to get the permission using the navigator object.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      .then(function(stream) {
        console.log('You let me use your mic!')
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('No mic for you!')
      });
```

Also you need to run it on HTTPS and on a website instead of using IP addresses

Comment: It shows in console but how can we show modal to user .

Comment: you need to replace the console.log logic with whatever you use to show modals

Comment: @SaranshKataria : I have some javascript code in my flask webserver, when I run it on localhost, I can record easily. But when the code is on the server, when I press the button for **Record**, I don't see any recording start, do I need to run it on `HTTPS` instead of `HTTP` and on a website? Isn't `HTTPS` more about being secure?

Comment: @aspiring1 since media and camera are powerful features, the web standards enforce them to work only on HTTPS websites. You can read more about it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: The popup in my chrome browser has Allow and Block buttons interchanged. Any browser setting for that?